# Нет перевода для просмотра календаря посещений

Tags: дефект, локализация

Заметил вот здесь отсутствие переводов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот предложил перевод:

[Нажмите, чтобы просмотреть календарь ежедневных посещений](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17915)

Answer (score 1):

> *"Не репутации ради, а порядка для..."*
> Данный ответ дан, чтобы можно было отфильтровать вопросы по локализации, не имеющие переводов.
>  Голосовать за него не нужно, а вот принять ответ или закрыть - желательно.

**Данное сообщение переведено:**

> Click to view daily visit calendar
> Нажмите для просмотра календаря ежедневных посещений
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17915

В интерфейсе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]